# add “loading” animation in jQuery function after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I need to add “loading” animation in jQuery function after button click

so, i have next function:

```
function get_revpopup_cart( product_id, action, quantity ) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
    if ( action == "catalog" ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
            dataType: 'json',

        beforeSend: function(){
            $('body').addClass('blur2');
            $('#pagefader2').fadeIn(70);
        },
   .............
```

and this animation: `<div class="page_gif_progress_icon"><div class="circle"></div></div>`

botton: `<a onclick="get_revpopup_cart('103', 'catalog', '1');" data-toggle="tooltip" title="В корзину"><i class="fa fa-border fa-shopping-basket"><span class="prlistb">add in cart</span></i>`

I need to add “loading” animation `before $('body').addClass('blur2');`  that would open up and disappear after as the function is executed

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but your solution does not work for me.
I solved the problem this way:

```
function get_revpopup_cart( product_id, action, quantity ) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
    if ( action == "catalog" ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
            dataType: 'json',

        beforeSend: function(){

            $('body').append('<div class="page_gif_progress_icon"><div class="circle"></div></div>').addClass('blur2');
            $('#pagefader2').fadeIn(70);
        },
```

and add this `$(".page_gif_progress_icon").remove();`

Comment: You just did exactly the same but I created variable for your loading element. Maybe I did some typo when declaring it. Still glad you have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you needed:

```
function get_revpopup_cart( product_id, action, quantity ) {
  //create reference to your loading animation node 
  var preloader = $('<div>')
                  .addClass('page_gif_progress_icon').
                  .append($('<div>').addClass('circle'));
  quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
  if ( action == "catalog" ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',

        beforeSend: function(){
            //add your preloader
            $('body').append(preloader);
            $('body').addClass('blur2');
            $('#pagefader2').fadeIn(70);
        success: function (data) {
            //do stuff with data and remove node
            preloader.remove();
        }
    },
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your solution does not work for me.
I solved the problem this way (check pls my own answer)